# how to install jdk 1.8 into jdeveloper 12.1.3.0.0

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am trying to downgrade from Jdeveloper 12.2.1.2.0 to Jdeveloper 12.1.3.0.0 but i faced incompatibility with java libraries.

I already followed these instructions 
http://markchensblog.blogspot.com/2014/06/change-jdk-used-by-jdeveloper.html
and i replaced the jdk of Jdeveloper 12.1.3.0.0 with the one in Jdeveloper 12.2.1.2.0 but i still can't run my project and em.createStoredProcedureQuery is not working nor @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)

should i update something else ?

Comment: You should go for 12.2.1.4.0, it fix a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the 12.1.3 certification doc:

> JDeveloper 12.1.3 can be configured to develop/compile against JDK 8,
>   and introduces support for JDK 8 language features. However, the
>   JDeveloper process must be running with JDK 7.

So you can compile it for 1.8.0 ut it would not run the app e.g. if you use ADF. You need to make it work with JDK 1.7.0